# Can I use SELECT AS to redefine table names in MySQL+PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I know a little about `SELECT AS` in MySQL, but I was wondering if there is a way to redefine table names for later use. For instance, I have a table named 'nb2013', but if I send my exported data to someone else (to install it on his server) he may want to change the names of the tables to what suits him, as 'nb2013' may already exist in his database.

Can I `DEFINE` the names in PHP so that PHP will still request the right table from MySQL?

Comment: Yes. You could define a constant or use a variable for the table name. You would just then need to use that constant/variable in your queries in place of the table name.

Comment: You can parametrize table name when you build SQL statement,  and have somewhere a settings file that will specify the table name mappings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable as table name. In your config you can then for instance define the table name variables.

Comment: Ah, yeah, of course. The only thing is, I would have to go in and turn it all into variables. Maybe next time :)